# POST requests to ASP site don't bring a good result

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I try to create POST request to ASP site (just like in Firefox), for get JSON response.
But in my code response is html, not JSON.

[link to site](http://www.polskieradio.pl/10,Czworka)

Firebug Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 11:32:22 GMT
Content-Length: 101
```

Firebug Request Headers:

```
POST /Portal/WebPageMethods/Playlista/playlist.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.polskieradio.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.polskieradio.pl/10,Czworka.json
Content-Length: 17
Cookie: cookies-accepted=true; ASP.NET_SessionId=35p3kig5t5cmlikubnlnytlh
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

source code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://www.polskieradio.pl/Portal/WebPageMethods/Playlista/playlist.aspx?program=4&count=1"
payload = { "Host": "www.polskieradio.pl",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Language": "pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer": "http://www.polskieradio.pl/10,Czworka",
        "Content-Length": "17",
        "Cookie": "cookies-accepted=true; ASP.NET_SessionId=5l1eezrjfdyvvevxushojtc2",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print r.content
```

How to do this properly?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a little bit different...

Look at this example:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

`Accept` is a header, not a payload.

Everything you are sending as payload, are, in fact, headers.
Your POST payload may be `program=4&count=1`, or you can do a GET.

--- ADDITION with final solution

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://www.polskieradio.pl/Portal/WebPageMethods/Playlista/playlist.aspx"

data = 'program=4&count=1'
headers = { 
        'User-Agent': 'curl/7.35.0',
        'Host': 'www.polskieradio.pl',
        'Accept':'*/*',
        'Proxy-Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: When I use it this way: `post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)` response content is the same: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Did you send your payload AS headers? You need this line, and to modify your code to send those headers AS headers, not as data.

Comment: Indeed, its not returning json... How did you do the first attempt with Firefox? What did you change to make it work?

Comment: I just use Firebug network tool to find this request and I want to do the same with python script.

Comment: Got it! The problem is on the website. It does not recognize json as payload for POST. You need to send raw data. Look at my edited post above.